# Is there anything similar to Selenium IDE that would run on Internet Explorer 7?

Tags: unit-testing, selenium

I need to develop Web functional testing for an application that currently supports only IE 7+. I'd also like to have my tests exported in Java so that I can have them integrated with my Java codebase

Answer (score 3):

You can record tests in Selenium IDE on Firefox and then export them to Java (File > Export Test Case As...). You can then using a testing framework such as JUnit or TestNG to run your tests with Selenium RC. To test in Internet Explorer 7, set your browser string to *iexplore (HTA mode) or *iexploreproxy and run the RC on a machine with version 7 installed.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium RC can run on [IE 7](http://seleniumhq.org/about/platforms.html#browsers) and you can do more with it because you can write the tests in high-level languages like Java and Ruby.